# Fit text into container

Tags: algorithm, optimization, line-breaks, tex

There is a text (possibly quite long). And there is a container of height and width. How do I make the text (all of it) fit to the container? It is possible only to adjust inter-character spacing (kerning) and inter-word spacing. I don't really care whether the text will be too packed - I just what all of it to be there inside.

To rephrase the question, I need an efficient algorithm for line breaking where the cost is the "packedness" of lines.

I know about Knuth-Plass algorithm, used in TeX but it is somewhat difficult to implement and I'm not even sure if it is usable in this scenario. I also could use genetic algorithm but that might be an overkill.

Comment: The Knuth-Plass was developed precisely for the scenario you described, so it should be usable. In terms of simplicity, always assume the existing algorithm is the simplest possible until you have fully understood the problem - most complexity in computer programs was introduced for a reason.

Comment: Do you want to do this in TeX or in some other language?

Comment: Some other language - I don't really care which one as long as it is at least somewhat common.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Fit text into given box by adjusting the fontsize](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26002/5764)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea.

First of all, estimate how many lines you would like the text to be, let that number be `n`. Then, suppose the number of characters in the text is `c`, then you should break the text into lines such that no line contains more than `floor(c / n)`  characters (you can do that greedily), let's call that `cPerLine`. (Note that you can also use dynamic programming to do the "word wrapping" for less "raggedness" (i.e., difference between lengths of lines), see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_wrap for details)

Suppose the average width for each character (depending on the size you're using, and you might want to use a monospaced font like *Courier New*) is `w` pixels. If the container's width is `x`, then you can calculate the character spacing easily: `floor(x / cPerline) - w`. You also need to consider **line spacing**, so if the average height of each character is `h`, and the container's height is `y`, similarly, the line spacing should be `floor(y / n) - h`.

Hope this helped in any manner.